# How do I pass a List<ClassType> as a parameter of another class?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a code where I have 2 classes, a "Commune" class which takes some parameters, and a "Region" class which is supposed to take a List object I initialise in the main and where I add all the communes manually into it.
The idea is that when a new Region object is made it checks through the whole List and checks if each Communes region corresponds with the Region Object declared name and then adds that Commune into that region.
The issue I'm encountering is that when I try to create a new Region the List does not seem to pass entirely into the class and then throws an error.

```
static class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            //string name, int department, string country, string mayor, int population
            var communes = new List<Commune>();
            
            Commune Au = new Commune("Aubervilliers", 95100, "Paris", "may", -500);
            Commune Ar = new Commune("Argenteuill", 95100, "Paris", "may", 121665);
            Commune SD = new Commune("SAINT-DEnis", 93000, "Paris", "may", 42069);
            Commune Br = new Commune("BrON", 69029, "Lyon", "Jérémie Bréaud", 42244);

            communes.Add(Au);
            communes.Add(SD);
            communes.Add(Ar);
            communes.Add(Br);

            //string _region List<Commune> cities string prefect string chief
            Region Paris = new Region("Paris", communes, "Prefect of Paris", "Chief of Paris");

            Paris.Tostring();
            Paris.TotalPop();
            Paris.InRegion("Puteaux");
            Paris.InRegion("Aubervilliers");
            Paris.Sort();
            Paris.Tostring();
        }

    }
```

(They are in different files in case that explains the issue)

```
public class Region
    {
        private string _region;
        private List<Commune> cities;
        private string prefect;
        private string chief;

        public Region(string _r, List<Commune> c, string p, string C){
            _region = _r;

            foreach (Commune com in c)
            {
                if(_r == com.Region){

                    cities.Add(com);
                }
            }
            prefect = p;
            chief = C;
        }
//More irrelevant code this way...
```

And here's the error.

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

cities was null.
```

Comment: You never initialize `cities`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate the `cities` list:

```
cities = new List<Commune>();
```

before you can actually add items to it.

You can either do this inside your `Region` method, or directly in your initial declaration:

```
private List<Commune> cities = new List<Commune>();
```

Comment: Oh I thought private List<Commune> cities was how you initialised. What does adding = new List<Commune>() do exactly? My teacher and I were wracking our brains over this.

Comment: @Jeromeo, `List<Commune> cities;` is *declaring* a variable. To simplify, You are telling the compiler you will use an object of this type in the code. However, this object does not exist yet. By doing: `List<Commune> cities = new List<Commune>()`, or a shorthand: `List<Commune> cities = new()` you are *creating* a new object.

Comment: @KifoPL, Oh okay I see. I think my confusion came from not having to do that for other variables string, int, bool. But It makes sense now that you explain it. Does that mean that in my getters and setter I should also declare them as new()?
 Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Jeromeo you might want to look at: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/csharp and watch the beginner video series and then work through some of tutorials to learn the basics of C#.